# R - how to filter after a certain date by group in a different DF

Tags: r

I would like some help if possible as I am new to R in filtering after a certain date and then summing the results.

For example, we have these organisations:

[image]

And in these organisations I want to know the consecutive sum of the recent 1's.

For example - A would Return 3 - B would return 1 and C would return 0 and D would also return 1.

The reason being for i.e. B is the most recent date was a 1 - failure but the week before was a success.

I have made some code to pull out the max date of the last 0 (pass) and have this saved in a different DF:
[image]

How would I apply this filter (second image/df) to my first dataframe only keeping the most recent dates i.e. the most recent consecutive 1's.

Or if there is a better way to tell r to read the most recent date and add columns until it hits a  0 column by row that would also be appreciated. I tried to have it count the highest consecutive numbers but if the dataframe was other a bigger time period, it would only show the largest failings in the past and I only need the most recent data.

I am new to this so any feedback in language or this query would be appreciated.

My current Code:

```
Trade_MCAD <- read_excel ("C:/Users/FiercePC/OneDrive/Desktop/Dates MS3 KPI Example/Trade/missed bin.xlsx", sheet=3)

Trade_MCAD$Date <- as.Date(Trade_MCAD$Date)

Trade_MCMaxD <- Trade_MCAD %>%
  group_by(Organisation) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date))

Trade_MC0 <- Trade_MCAD[!grepl("1", Trade_MCAD$Collection),]

Trade_MC0 <- Trade_MC0 %>%
  group_by(Organisation) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more elegant solutions, but one option is to create variable with the number of repeating instances, the take the last one:

Since you didnt provide reproducible data, here is some similar sample data (edited to use TarJae's more accurate data):

```
df <- structure(list(Organisation = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F", "G", "G", "G"), Date = c("2022-03-01", 
"2022-03-08", "2022-03-15", "2022-03-01", "2022-03-08", "2022-03-15", 
"2022-03-02", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-02", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-02", 
"2022-03-03", "2022-03-01", "2022-03-08", "2022-03-15"), Collection = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", 
"0")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
# generate counts of sequential repeats by Organization
df <- df %>% group_by(Organisation) %>% 
  mutate(count = sequence(rle(as.character(Collection))$lengths)) 

# recode counts for those with collection == 0
df$count <- ifelse(df$Collection == 0, 0, df$count)

# select the last date with collection
df %>% group_by(Organisation) %>% 
  slice(2:n()) %>% # Keep if you want to ignore first entry
  filter(Collection == 1 | all(Collection == 0)) %>%
  slice(n())
```

Output:

```
#   Organisation Date       Collection count
# <chr>        <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 A            2022-03-15 1              3
# 2 B            2022-03-15 1              1
# 3 C            2022-03-16 0              0
# 4 D            2022-03-16 1              1
# 5 E            2022-03-02 0              0
# 6 F            2022-03-03 1              1
# 7 G            2022-03-15 0              0
```

Comment: The sample data I made is different than the posted image - I edited to use your data that is more accurate to the question, thank you

Comment: With the two answers provided they didn't work as following:

jpsmith - If I have for example another organisation named F - that has a 1 value for collection. It will count that 1 and also count the previous organisation i.e. D's 1's also. Meaning although I only want it to return a 1 it'd return a 2. 
Org  Date              Collection
D 16/03/2022 1
F 16/03/2022 1

Return: D - 1, F - 2 where in reality both of them are 1. It needs that 0 to stop counting. is there anyway to say do it by the 0 and then also stop counting or count new by a new organisation?

Comment: Ah great point - see if the edit I made solves this problem, where we run the counts after grouping. I created sample data with group "E" and "F" that both have only one observation, with "E" having `Collection == 0` and "F" having `Collection == 1`

Comment: One final point - If I have an organisation i.e. C which has 3 data points i.e. 01/03/2022 - 05/03/2022 and then the 09/03/2022 - If the 1st is a collection (1) and the 05th/9th are 0's then this also produces a 1 rather then a 0. Is there a way to make it state a 0 or have it remove the organisation C due to its max date being a 1.

Comment: I have in the meantime added before jpsmiths code and after read in:
Trade_MC0 <- Trade_MC

Trade_MC0 <- Trade_MC0 %>%
  group_by(Organisation) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date))

Trade_MC0 <- Trade_MC0[!grepl("1", Trade_MC0$Collection),]

Trade_MC0 <- Trade_MC0[,c(1)]

Trade_MCAD <- Trade_MCAD[!Trade_MCAD$Organisation %in% Trade_MC0$Organisation,] 
This filters the work to remove those with recent 0's such as organisation C. IF they could be included with it returning a 0 that would be better. If not that is more then understandable.

Comment: I've added a new Organization, "G" that reflects this (if I understood you correctly) - the first entry is == 1 and the subsequent ones == 0, so you want the final data to sat 0. You can ignore the first entry with an additional `slice()` command in dplyr

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Organisation) %>% 
  mutate(x = sequence(rle(as.character(Collection))$lengths)) %>% 
  summarise(y = ifelse(max(Collection)==1, max(x), min(Collection)))
```

```
  Organisation     y
  <chr>        <int>
1 A                3
2 B                1
3 C                0
4 D                1
```

data:

```
structure(list(Organisation = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "D", "D"), Date = c("2022-03-01", "2022-03-08", "2022-03-15", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-03-08", "2022-03-15", "2022-03-02", "2022-03-16", 
"2022-03-02", "2022-03-16"), Collection = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: This works really well apart from if I have older data which has a bigger consecutive series. I.e.:
Organisation Date Collection
A 11/01/2022 0
A 18/01/2022 1
A 25/01/2022 1
A 01/02/2022 1
A 08/02/2022 1
A 15/02/2022 0
A 22/02/2022 0
A 01/03/2022 1
A 08/03/2022 1
A 15/03/2022 1

In this the most recent series would hopefully return a value of 3 - but it actually returns a value of 4 as that is the max consecutive series. Is there anyway to edit it so it'd count the consecutive dates by the max data rather then the max consecutive numbers?